# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader

Tags: java, maven

Facing issue while reading large excel from blob.

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
        <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>
```

**code**

```
Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder()
                            .rowCacheSize(100)    // number of rows to keep in memory (defaults to 10)
                            .bufferSize(4096)     // buffer size to use when reading InputStream to file (defaults to 1024)
                            .open(in);
```

**Getting below exception**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
>         at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader.(StreamingReader.java:45)
>         at com.scmcaf.dao.FileUploadChildDAOImpl.excuteSchedulerForLineDetails(FileUploadChildDAOImpl.java:131)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
>         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.excuteSchedulerForLineDetails(Unknown Source)
>         at com.scmcaf.controller.TestController.doSomething(TestController.java:425)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
>         at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExenter
>   code hereecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of slf4j in that you explicitly declare in your pom.xml

Try using the 1.7.12 version if you need it explicitly or remove it as it is a dependency for xlsx-streamer

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
 <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
```

For more information on how maven works in case of multiple version of the same dependency read the chapter Transitive Dependencies 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html :

> Dependency mediation - this determines what version of a dependency
>   will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are encountered.
>   Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition"
>   which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to
>   your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always guarantee a
>   version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM. Note that if
>   two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree,
>   until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since
>   Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first
>   declaration wins.
>
> ```
> "nearest definition" means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies, eg. if
> ```
>
> dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A
>   -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a
>   dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0

Comment: Tried but still the same issue.

Comment: @Shrikant Ganorkar Did you clean correctly your project ?

Comment: @Shrikant Ganorkar Do you have a dependency to slf4j-api in your pom perhaps ?

Comment: No... is the reason ?

Comment: After adding provided dependency getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal

Comment: Mmm this is something else looks like you are missing the batik library here. see https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.xmlgraphics%7Cbatik%7C1.9.1%7Cpom

Comment: if I remove provided dependency then it works fine... If i read large excel then getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader.(StreamingReader.java:45) exception

Comment: Your problem with the excel file is probably what StreamingReader si trying to tell you but cant access to the slf4j library for some reason. Can't help you more here as this would need to look at your project as a whole.

Comment: Referring below code to read large excel file  InputStream in = lob.getBinaryStream();
    //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
    System.out.println("Before reading excel from blob...");
    
    Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder()
            .rowCacheSize(100)    // number of rows to keep in memory (defaults to 10)
            .bufferSize(4096)     // buffer size to use when reading InputStream to file (defaults to 1024)
            .open(in);

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a SLF4J API to your dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api

When it is missing some class, you can search for the class in mvnrepository.com. Just copy there `org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`

Comment: Yes, you can check if all dependencies are ok, maybe when this class is loaded another class is required indirectly. Try to copy an open source project pom.xml or to debug when the class is loaded

Answer (score -1):

This is a tricky one. I had a similar problem like this with log4j. 
Navigate to the directory of your JRE e.g:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib
```

create a folder `endorsed` and drop the jar `log4j-1.2.17.jar` (use the relevant version in your case) in it. Then restart your application.

This solved it for me.